# JavaScript selectionchange event for a particular element only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to implement a JavaScrit `selectionchange` event on a particular `div` element, so if the user selects text from the DOM I want to show a highlighter box. I have implemented this for web with an `onmouseup` event. But I am stuck trying to implement this for mobile devices.

For mobile browsers I am binding `document.selectionchange` event on the DOM, but I want this to only apply for a particular element which has the `content-editable` class. So the highlighter will show only when the user selected text within the container on page which has the `content-editable` class.

```
document.addEventListener("selectionchange", function(evt) { 
  // Now this functionality only apply for content-editable class div.
});
```

How can I implement this functionality? Perhaps it could be implemented with a recursive function to find `parentElement`'s class of `anchorNode` of selected text like:

```
var selection = ctrl.window.getSelection();
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you bind it just to the specific element instead of the whole document?

Comment: @Barmar selectionchange event only work on document.

Comment: Do u find a better anwser? My thought is the same as you. To recursively find the parent node, then decide the event should be processed or not.

Answer (score 7):

Listen for the [`selectstart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/selectstart_event) event of your target element instead. Only get the selection when this event is fired.

```
const targetDiv = document.getElementById("interestingDiv");
function logSelection() {  
  console.log(document.getSelection().toString());
}
targetDiv.addEventListener("selectstart", () => {
  console.log("Selection started in targetDiv");
  document.addEventListener("selectionchange", logSelection);
});
```

The `selectstart` event fires as soon as a new selection is made, so you will need some way to get the selection once it's complete. We can listen to `selectionchange`, with some way to stop listening after the selection is made. One option is to stop listening on `mouseleave`:

```
targetDiv.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
 document.removeEventListener("selectionchange", logSelection);
})
```