# I want to know if any word is selected within the "id"

Tags: javascript, selection, getelementbyid, selectionchanged

```
document.getElementById('analyseArticleBody').addEventListener('selectionchange', () => {
  console.log('hello')
  this.doubleClick()
})
```

I want to know if any word is selected inside this section

Comment: What have you tried so far? What was the result?

Comment: Can you create a demo and share it?

Comment: I Got the answer.. I have used mouseUp event over the section and used the window.getSelection()

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2C6fB/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the length of `document.getSelection()`:

```js
document.addEventListener('selectionchange', (ev) => {
  var selection = document.getSelection().toString();
  console.log(selection.length + " characters selected");
})
```

```html
Test text
```

Comment: but selectionChange works on the full document as far I know. Anyways thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As noted on this other answer, this event only attaches to the document but you could use `selectstart` for a specific element.

[JavaScript selectionchange event for a particular element only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46109139/javascript-selectionchange-event-for-a-particular-element-only)

Comment: selectionstart don't meet my requirement, as it is fired whenever the selection starts..I want it when one is finished with the selection.Link helped me though.Thanks.